# how can I print a web page with all its css style attached to the page?

Tags: css, printing, html

I want to add a print button to enable users to print my web page. However when I print all the css styles are lost. It seems the printer only keeps the basic html elements. If I also want to print out the page exactly as it looks like in a browser, what should I do? I mean if I use a color printer it will print a colorful page with css styles on it. When I use a black and white printer it should print light colors as white and dark colors as grey or black.

Answer (score 17):

If you have `media="screen"` on your `link` element, try to remove it or replace with `media="all"`.

Comment: In my case there was no `media` attribute at all, but adding `media="all"` worked. I glanced past this answer at first because I knew I didn't have `media="screen"` on my link.

Comment: media="all" Works like a charm.

Comment: I'm opening the popup window to print using JS. In my case I don't have any link.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [this](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/05/05/how-to-create-a-simple-print-css-for-your-site/) and [this](http://line25.com/tutorials/handy-tips-for-creating-a-print-css-stylesheet), that should help.

Basically you need to add a css print statement.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="URL to your print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

Answer (score 3):

CSS style-sheets have an attribute `media`. It specifies to what media this css is applicable. Possible media types are listed [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmedia.shtml).

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">
   @import "myCss.css";
</style>
```

OR

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">
```