# How to print html page without breaking css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, printing

I have a html page which I have designed with bootstrap. I used window.print to print that html page with A4 size but my style broke when I print that page with that button. How do I print the html page without breaking css?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I print a web page with all its css style attached to the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384985/how-can-i-print-a-web-page-with-all-its-css-style-attached-to-the-page)

Comment: Have you searched Google and SO for a solution ? there are a lot of questions on this topic here on SO and a lot of solutions