# Saving web page as pdf looking exactly the way it looks in browser

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf

I have a web page that is dynamically generated by php. Sometimes I need to save that page to share processed data. I usually save it in Opera browser and it works perfectly fine. However some people may not have Opera or virtual printer installed. Is there a simple way to save page as pdf by JavaScript? Or maybe on the server side by PHP? I've been trying jsPDF, but it is terrible. It doesn't see fonts, it doesn't work with utf-8, it doesn't display css styles properly and generally you need to re-create that page from the scratch if you want decent result. I just need magical button Save that will do the same thing Opera does. Does such thing exist? If yes, where can I find it? If not, why?

Comment: If you're using Chrome (or Firefox), you can try this https://superuser.com/a/1271790

Comment: Solution for exact browsers is not what I'm looking for. Person may have Edge or Vivaldi or whatever they find pleasing. I would like to find solution that would work for all.

Comment: This might be helpful then https://stackoverflow.com/q/3384985/3894173

Comment: jsPDF isn't *terrible*, the approach You described is a common mistake, I believe, due to the fact that front-end developers are (mostly) thinking `HTML/CSS` first. I am using instead a PDF-first approach: 1) design the PDF using native functions 2) with the same code, I am also able to draw a preview  by redirecting lines, rectangles, pictures and text to a HTML5 `canvas`. Such way, my PDF corresponds always 100% with my preview.

Comment: dear deblocker, it was terrible for the purpose I tried to use it for. It may work great for you but that's now what was my question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Phantom JS for that. http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html

Comment: I don't need browser. I need solution that will work independently in any browser.

Comment: phantomJS is a headless browser running server side - it uses the webkit engine. But due the fact that it is server side you can use any browser on the client side. It generates a pdf on the server. The clients browser is just downloading this pdf.

See the rasterize example

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js



https://coderwall.com/p/5vmo1g/use-phantomjs-to-create-pdfs-from-html

Comment: Thank you for explanation. The bad thing it doesn't work: not with your rasterize.js, not with example from phantomjs.org https://yadi.sk/i/h1aGDQtr3YPY54

Comment: i am generating pixelperfect multipage pdf with phantomjs running on ubuntu 16.04 - so what exactly doesnt work?

Comment: I use Windows 7 as server...The message you can see on the screenshot above is "Invalid character '\u0008'
  phantomjs://repl-input:1 in global code"

Comment: https://www.joecolantonio.com/2014/10/14/how-to-install-phantomjs/. And here a [tutorial on youtube](https://youtu.be/L8Lw53MjDdY)

Comment: thanks again. I got it to work though it renders pages a bit differently (for example it doesn't use align-self value from css). One problem however is still is unresolved. In examples it works with other pages. Is there a way to generate pdf from page protected by cookies, sessions, ip checks etc?

Comment: There are a few things regarding css which can give you a hard time :D As i mentioned before it uses the webkit engine. When the last phantom version came out things like flexbox just reached the browsers - so use the "-webkit" prefixes for those rules. I like this tool btw https://autoprefixer.github.io/

It is totaly possible to write a phantom js script which logs in to your site but you have to share the login with the phantom script. Thats why i personaly moved to filling a template file with data and then simply open that temporary file with phantom.js, create pdf and remove by php.

Comment: Thank you again very much. I wrote a script which allows phantom js to generate really nice looking pdfs (after a tiny bit of css editing) without the need to create pdf template from the scratch. I'm sorry I can't upvote you. You were very helpful, kind sir.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)