# writing-mode: vertical-rl; Not Working on print

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to print a table with some column name in vertical text display , I create the the following html code , when I'm trying to print my html page , the vertical text is not displayed on the print preview

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
           .verticalTableHeader {
         writing-mode: vertical-rl;
         text-orientation:mixed;
         white-space: pre;
         }
         @media print {
            .verticalTableHeader {
         writing-mode: vertical-rl;
         text-orientation:mixed;
         white-space: pre;
         }
        }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
                  <div >
          
             
            <table border="1"
               >
               <thead>
                  <tr>
                     <th>Client</th>
                     <th>description</th>
                     <th>Type</th>
                     <th  class="verticalTableHeader">Emplacement  </br>géographique</th>
                     <th  class="verticalTableHeader">Nature de </br>l'autorisation</th>
                     <th  class="verticalTableHeader">Critique</th>
                     <th  class="verticalTableHeader">Début planifié</th>
                     <th  >Fin réelle</th>
                     <th  >Statut</th>
                  </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody id="dd">
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
    
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Chrome Version 101.0.4951.67 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384985/how-can-i-print-a-web-page-with-all-its-css-style-attached-to-the-page

Answer (score 0):

For me, putting the "th" text in a div works.

```
<thead>
  <tr>
     ...
     <th>Type</th>
     <th><div class="verticalTableHeader">Emplacement</div></th>
     ...
  </tr>
</thead>
```